# curl redirect not properly working

Tags: php, redirect, curl

My function is supposed to get the destination URL of $url:

```
function getUrl($url)
{
    $user_agent='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)';
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $timeout = 10; // set to zero for no timeout 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $curl = curl_exec($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $header;

}

function get_url_list() {

 $url = "http://www.webliste.ch/click.aspx?nr=148252";
 $result=getUrl($url);
 print_r($result);echo "<br>";
}

get_url_list();
```

This results in the following:

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.webliste.ch/click.aspx?nr=148252
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 320
    [request_size] => 139
    ...
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

I am at a loss, because the URL is redirecting, and if I echo $ch, I get the redirected website.

Anyone know what's the cause of this?

The following doesnt work either:

```
$final_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

The output is the same as $result['url'], which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: What is the problem? You getting redirected website because you have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true.

Comment: Hm...What are you expect? You are set the follow location property and got the target page. What page you need?

Comment: I need the final page, after all the redirections have happened.

Answer (score 1):

I've analyzed what actually happens and now I see that the redirect is not caused by a redirect header on that page instead it's with JavaScript instantly submitting a form and redirecting you to the start page.

Might be hard to determine the URL of the page but what you can do is look for a `<form>` tag and then find the URL in its `action` attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
   <head id="Head1">
      <title></title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <form id="form1" action="http://www.taxiherold.ch">
         <div id="panGo" align="center">
            <script type="text/javascript">
               document.getElementById('form1').submit();
            </script>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

So try this code now:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.webliste.ch/click.aspx?nr=148252');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$url = $xpath->query('//body/form');
$url = ($url->length == 1 ? $url->item(0)->getAttribute('action') : null);


var_dump($url);
```

Will output:

[image]

Comment: The output is the wrong URL (it's the initial one, not the redirected one), should have included that in my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

this class that i wrote can help you

this class return you all header information like redirection ,...

```
 function HeaderProc($response,$Run="",$String=1/*[Is 1 IF Use for String Mode ]*/){
          print_r($response);
          if($String==1){
             $response=explode("\r\n",$response);  
          }
          $PartHeader=0;
          $out[$PartHeader]=array();
          while(list($key,$val)=each($response)){
              $name='';
              $value='';
              $flag=false;
              for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);$i++){
                  if($val[$i]==":"){
                      $flag=true;
                      for($j=$i+1;$j<strlen($val);$j++){
                        if($val[$i]=="\r" and $val[$i+1]=="\n"){    
                            break;
                        }
                        $value.=$val[$j];
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                  $name.=$val[$i]; 
              }
              if($flag){
                if($name=='' and $value==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                  if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){
                    if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                    }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$value;  
                    }
                  }else{
                    $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$value;
                  }
                }
              }else{
                if($name==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                    if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){ 
                      if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                      }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$name;  
                      }
                    }else{
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$name; 
                    }
                } 
              }
              if($Run!=""){
                $Run($name,$value);  
              }
          }
          return $out;
}

 class cURL { 
    var $headers; 
    var $user_agent; 
    var $compression; 
    var $cookie_file; 
    var $proxy; 
    var $Cookie; 
    function CookieAnalysis($Cookie){//convert str cookie to array cookie 
       //echo $Cookie;
       $this->Cookie=array();
       preg_replace_callback("~(.*?)=(.*?);~si",function($m){$this->Cookie[trim($m[1])]=trim($m[2]);},' '.$Cookie.'; ');
       return $this->Cookie;
    }
    function cURL($cookies=false,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') {
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'; 
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
         $this->headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
         $this->user_agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (SepidarSoft [Organic Search Engine Crawler] Linux Edition) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5';
         $this->compression=$compression; 
         $this->proxy=$proxy; 
         $this->cookies=$cookies; 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
    } 
    function cookie($cookie_file) { 
         if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
         } else { 
            fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
            @fclose($this->cookie_file); 
         } 
    }
    function GET($url) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         $response = curl_exec($process);
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function POST($url,$data) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         $response = curl_exec($process); 
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function error($error) { 
         echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b><br>$error</div></center>";
         die; 
    } 
 }
```

sample:

```
  $cc = new cURL(); 
  print_r( $cc->POST('http://www.domain.com'));
```

for old php

```
function HeaderProc($response,$Run="",$String=1/*[Is 1 IF Use for String Mode ]*/){
          if($String==1){
             $response=explode("\r\n",$response);  
          }
          $PartHeader=0;
          $out[$PartHeader]=array();
          while(list($key,$val)=each($response)){
              $name='';
              $value='';
              $flag=false;
              for($i=0;$i<strlen($val);$i++){
                  if($val[$i]==":"){
                      $flag=true;
                      for($j=$i+1;$j<strlen($val);$j++){
                        if($val[$i]=="\r" and $val[$i+1]=="\n"){    
                            break;
                        }
                        $value.=$val[$j];
                      }
                      break;
                  }
                  $name.=$val[$i]; 
              }
              if($flag){
                if($name=='' and $value==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                  if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){
                    if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                    }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$value;  
                    }
                  }else{
                    $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$value;
                  }
                }
              }else{
                if($name==''){
                    $PartHeader++;  
                }else{
                    if(isset($out[$PartHeader][$name])){ 
                      if(is_array($out[$PartHeader][$name])){   
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][]=$value;
                      }else{
                        $T=$out[$PartHeader][$name];
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=array();
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][0]=$T;  
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name][1]=$name;  
                      }
                    }else{
                        $out[$PartHeader][$name]=$name; 
                    }
                } 
              }
              if($Run!=""){
                $Run($name,$value);  
              }
          }
          return $out;
}

class cURL { 
    var $headers; 
    var $user_agent; 
    var $compression; 
    var $cookie_file; 
    var $proxy; 
    var $Cookie; 
    function CookieAnalysis($Cookie){//convert str cookie to array cookie 
       //echo $Cookie;
       $this->Cookie=array();
       preg_match("~(.*?)=(.*?);~si",' '.$Cookie.'; ',$M);
       $this->Cookie[trim($M[1])]=trim($M[2]);
       return $this->Cookie;
    }
    function cURL($cookies=false,$cookie='cookies.txt',$compression='gzip',$proxy='') {
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'; 
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch';
         $this->headers[] = 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8';
         $this->headers[] = 'Cache-Control:max-age=0';
         $this->headers[] = 'Connection:keep-alive';
         $this->user_agent = 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (SepidarSoft [Organic Search Engine Crawler] Linux Edition) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) SepidarBrowser/1.0.100.52 Safari/536.5';
         $this->compression=$compression; 
         $this->proxy=$proxy; 
         $this->cookies=$cookies; 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) $this->cookie($cookie); 
    } 
    function cookie($cookie_file) { 
         if (file_exists($cookie_file)) { 
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
         } else { 
            fopen($cookie_file,'w') or $this->error('The cookie file could not be opened. Make sure this directory has the correct permissions');
            $this->cookie_file=$cookie_file; 
            @fclose($this->cookie_file); 
         } 
    }
    function GET($url) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process,CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         $response = curl_exec($process);
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
           if(!is_array($HeaderP['Set-Cookie']))continue;
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function POST($url,$data) { 
         $process = curl_init($url); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent); 
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
         if ($this->cookies == TRUE) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file);
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_ENCODING , $this->compression); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
         if ($this->proxy) curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_PROXY, $this->proxy); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
         curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
         $response = curl_exec($process); 
         $header_size = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
         $result['Header'] = HeaderProc(substr($response, 0, $header_size),'',1);
         foreach($result['Header'] as $HeaderK=>$HeaderP){
            if(!is_array($HeaderP['Set-Cookie']))continue;
           foreach($HeaderP['Set-Cookie'] as $key=>$val){
             $result['Header'][$HeaderK]['Set-Cookie'][$key]=$this->CookieAnalysis($val);
           }
         }
         $result['Body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
         $result['HTTP_State'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         $result['URL'] = curl_getinfo($process,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
         curl_close($process); 
         return $result; 
    }
    function error($error) { 
         echo "<center><div style='width:500px;border: 3px solid #FFEEFF; padding: 3px; background-color: #FFDDFF;font-family: verdana; font-size: 10px'><b>cURL Error</b><br>$error</div></center>";
         die; 
    } 
 }
```

sample:

```
  $cc = new cURL(); 
  print_r( $cc->POST('http://www.domain.com'));
```

Yahoo site sample header output

```
  [Header] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [HTTP/1.1 302 Found] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found
                [Date] =>  Sat, 02 Mar 2013 14:37:19 GMT
                [P3P] =>  policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
                [Cache-Control] =>  private
                [X-Frame-Options] =>  SAMEORIGIN
                [Set-Cookie] =>  fpc=d=a2polPzlISX4q5OZQBxq.CKduGwG2Wm1YrPD59ENCUl3uTzrs.8HlnpJROO8MWa6M.B8e1JuCsbW25qwqY5zEs.mA0_EVlAVPMhFCdfCxhZf6vWmmqpPm9bVzGYs8Y7IyTG7IFp9p0MN_FPQmzNM7I8XBu4iGCI8MbHWFvOMKmhN9MTkPC4KbNJ2izSK9xBXTedDnYw-&v=2; expires=Sun, 02-Mar-2014 14:37:19 GMT; path=/; domain=www.yahoo.com
                [Location] =>  http://en-maktoob.yahoo.com/?p=us
                [Vary] =>  Accept-Encoding
                [Content-Type] =>  text/html; charset=utf-8
                [Age] =>  0
                [Transfer-Encoding] =>  chunked
                [Connection] =>  keep-alive
                [Server] =>  YTS/1.20.13
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [HTTP/1.1 200 OK] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                [Date] =>  Sat, 02 Mar 2013 14:37:20 GMT
                [P3P] =>  policyref="http://info.yahoo.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
                [Cache-Control] =>  private
                [X-Frame-Options] =>  SAMEORIGIN
                [Set-Cookie] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [IU] => deleted
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [PH] => deleted
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [MSC] => t=1362235040X
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [fpc] => d=_7tfRPjaISWhpxKrzORZ47ywABwHrUd0vF3WBQH9UYD6KMC7fyjTBdcMMh1FYiufGwiXnhHgDV9gK_VrwVf.q.n_MoJj3B4OMV5Lw42TXrYN_xGhwsnsyUPvQTy79LJ.twkY0IQ3culhr0osKxe0MvGIPSRcYDWH13TUS5YhrnIP731WRyEDZlPh2gPUXxNc1nRtr7Y-&v=2
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [fpms] => p_30345347=%7B%22loc%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A1940330%2C%22city%22%3A%22Abu+Dhabi%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22UAE%22%7D%7D
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [fpc] => d=SaiDIsbaISXJV8ztcJqpafzGA13Lsq0TPQ7HJOn_.yLYWvNZF75ELqLKTLekfVYxmFj0OxOH_thzdIa9UNQIiwYXt99qJ8HNsqpWubAPIFaO1o36VbPBUz9Qu0Rzgzh6Qh.rJQnhPnj1m3NMeFlpYZ7kpVAsjL88RMdcGP82RMUEENd9mWXC7SkuY_CIR76Ne3pEgotZlVDVMABYyxJbM4N4jqG5zkC23Gy8epD4JzxcUuTWDyUn.LZaIqX1Gn6Fcn_f6de3&v=2
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [fpps] => _page=%7B%22wsid%22%3A%2221445690%22%7D
                            )

                        [7] => Array
                            (
                                [fpt] => d=Zc7DH53Xe9za_cphyvUoTpFDnmIFF977Sv9yIyBJtqtpcN4aLM18CC3FKuMd6AMXylr7FJjRBtWkJYiIdmrER9MPUOFt22FcF8rNk8Lu_kQMbAEra9CnHEhP0N8DVz6iKlRji6wGv_.3pOxmx_7Td1bq2D4RtVTE93P1kVGFgxlSV7Vtdf8JUxoRTq3dMKZuNQD5vY76rjiXf64lrQ89ONTWEpCGE3MxGVHnegZ71MiuKmYPLxH.AdNFzgw_EoD5QFWyxBxC3GNq7CarXzwJ5D4Uoiw690kzihlRQ66UgGj6sAdIIB_haiXQ6pJ7Q_w86gen6FBolLLiIBrDaujASks1fNzrWOfSH7HDn3GfqcCycIXcJDw_Xb8eGBgJVZFK2yuM0BF68NOW.nkACke1I.ufHsJXrvZH51Pg4dh9hMIsqeI-&v=1
                            )

                        [8] => Array
                            (
                                [fpc_s] => d=jbVQS4TaISWRQmb4Qu6ANMqdtfYe_QawTKJ.rdl.9vdhjLe6UHD_z3Pvh2HhUHGn2i4oPThLzibGfAmid4zCCnYjxdTbby8pCY566kgiSjnvroDbRszWKfTL4j8Bew5x1VnLUqLfpKWUq2jwAOj1WdBhiSajBzp_hg.8q8O1M0XO.hd7YXRtm66BnbOtcTli3arG1nfT96JakB5i8cyNrUMl1m4czoVB7MqJDipKCfQ.19r98RG0dJELW.fFXfry0AApcU8cweMqTTIuks1LAeVRngCAX7eRfB0eknd5DOqTpZlrMTmW.JjNnbI-&v=2
                            )

                    )

                [Vary] =>  Accept-Encoding
                [Content-Type] =>  text/html;charset=utf-8
                [Content-Encoding] =>  gzip
                [Age] =>  0
                [Transfer-Encoding] =>  chunked
                [Connection] =>  keep-alive
                [Server] =>  YTS/1.20.13
            )

    )
```

Comment: The ouput is the same as my function. It just returns $ch.

Comment: @Spurious what you mean this class return as array and you can see last redirection page and other information

Comment: If you want to have a look at the website I mentioned:
http://www.webliste.ch/click.aspx?nr=148252

My output is just the source code, thus the same as echo $ch in my function.
I would be glad, if you could check it on your machine and see if it's the same for you.

Comment: @Spurious you can't get redirect url because of this redirect by JavaScript

Comment: @Spurious yes by Parse body with `preg_match` or `DOMDocument`

Comment: @Spurious run my script it give you `body` too

Comment: I cant access the array with your script, it automatically dumps the code and I see the final webpage.

And is the body from the final page or before it redirects?

Comment: @Spurious if you remove `print_r` you can put output into the variable like `$output=$cc->POST('http://www.domain.com')` and you can access to body like  `$output['Body']`

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but body just dumps the source code and the page is loaded. So the source code is not the one with the URL in it that I need, correct`?

Comment: @Spurious in body is a `form` element in `action` attribute  you can see the URL of page for redirect.i told this page redirect by JavaScript and HTML

Comment: Thank you, I did a file put content operation to not get redirected and have a look at the source code, thank you very much again!